# How to find all css classes and its css attributes inside a certain div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i would like to find all classes and ids inside a certain div ! and these css attributes!

Example :

```
<div class="demo">
<div class="new_class">
<p id="para">This is Demo Paragraph</p>
<a style="background:#ccc">HyperLink</a>

</div>
</div>

<style>
.demo{

height:100px; width:100px; background:#FF0;

}
.new_class{height:40px; width:40px; background:#999;}
#para{color:#E1E1E1;}


</style>
```

Now The question is that: i would like to find all classes and ids which are used inside demo class ! and Their css values too(which style applying now. ).
I would like to find result as below :

```
<style>
.demo{

height:100px; width:100px; background:#FF0;

}
.new_class{height:40px; width:40px; background:#999;}
#para{color:#E1E1E1;}
a{background:#ccc;}

</style>
```

Comment: And what attempts have you made so far?

Comment: Use $(".demo").children() and then iterate through all to retrieve individual id, class and style attributes. But, all the output will be in javascript, not as a style tag you expect. Also, you won't be able to differentiate between inline style and other styles.

Answer (score 3):

OP, not sure what your purpose is, but in general, this can be useful. I had a project where I needed to embed a fancy template from one site onto a page on a different site with a very different, and conflicting stylesheet. I used some code similar to the following to grab every applied style from the original content, via [document.styleSheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets), then reapplied them all as inline styles, so I could put it onto the "parent" site without the stylesheets conflicting.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/so4oaypr/)**

**JS**

```
var selector,rule;
var result=[];
   var sheets = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i in sheets) {
        //rules or cssRules, depending on the browser
        var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
        //iterate over every css rule in the document
        for (var r in rules)
        {
            selector=rules[r].selectorText;
            rule=rules[r].cssText;
            //select demo itself, as well as all of its children
            $('.demo, .demo *').each(function () {
                //console.log($(this),selector);
                //for each element, see if it matches the current rule. add if it does
                if ($(this).is(selector))
                {
                    result.push(rule);                  
                }
            });
        }
    }
console.log(result);
//result[0] .demo { height: 100px; width: 100px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 0); }
//result[1] .new_class { height: 40px; width: 40px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(153, 153, 153); }
//result[2]  #para { color: rgb(225, 225, 225); }
```

Granted, you will have to tweak this on your own to do things like, removing duplicate styles that would occur if you were to apply this to a larger block of HTML, and for dealing with inline styles (which this does not attempt to do, but you can get them from the `style` attribute and work from there...), and possibly the computed style, which you can get with [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle), as indicated by the @Derek's answer. but this should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

To find all existing `id`, try:

```
var ids = [];
$(".demo *").each(function(){ this.id && ids.push(this.id); });
console.log(ids);
```

Do the same thing for `class` or anything else.

However, to get your expected output, you must first acquire the defined CSS style for each element. Which one should be included? `p` by default gets margins and paddings. Do you include those too? You will also need to dig into all the CSS declarations just to find the style that are applied, which is almost impossible to do.

For example,

```
<div class="yellow"></div>
<style>
    div.yellow:not(.blue){
        background: yellow;
    }
</style>
```

How do you get the background of the `<div>` tag? `.style.background`? Nah, it returns `""`. Well now you will have to reach into the CSS declaration with `document.styleSheets` to see which one applied. How do you even check if the rule `div.yellow:not(.blue)` matches your element? Good luck doing that. (There might be libraries that does this kind of thing, or maybe you can even utilize jQuery's internal selector engine with `.is`, though it will not be the same as in CSS) Another thing you can do is try `getComputedStyle`. It gives you every single computed styles that aren't even in your declaration. So what you are trying to do **is not possible to do**. (I don't even know what you are doing something like this.)